# Istanbul code coverage shows branch not covered in constructor

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, typeorm, nyc

I'm testing my nodejs written typescript with **mocha** and **chai**, for code coverage i'm using **nyc**.

as part of my project i'm also using **Typeorm** as ORM tool and using **inversify** as IoC container.

When writing unit test cases, code coverage says branch not covered at where ever is a decorator e.g. @Inject or @Response, etc., passed as a parameter either in constructor or to any method.

I'm suspecting

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

is causing the issue, but I can't make them false which causes Typeorm to fail.

[image: Code coverage report]

[image: Constructor issue]
Below is the **tsconfig.json**

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "mocha"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "migrations/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./dist"
  ]
}
```

npm commands for test and test coverage

```
"test": "mocha -r ts-node/register ./tests/unit/**/*.ts --exit",
"test:cov": "rimraf reports && rimraf .nyc_output && nyc mocha
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the **"@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript"** into the .nycrc.json to extends array and **"source-map-support/register"** into the .mocharc.json to require array resolved the issue

**.nycrs.json**

```
{
    "extends" : [
        "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "extension": [
        ".ts"
    ],
    "check-coverage": true,
    "lines": 0,
    "reporter": [
        "lcov",
        "text-summary"
    ],
    "report-dir": "reports/coverage",
    "all": true,
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules",
        "src/*.d.ts",
        "./dist",
        "./migrations",
        "./commitlint.config.js",
        "**/*.entity.ts",
        "**/I[A-Z]*.{ts}",
        "**/*.config.{ts}",
        "**/config.ts"

    ],
    "timeout": 4000
}
```

**.mocharc.json**

```
{
    "extension": [
      ".ts"
    ],
    "recursive": true,
    "require": [
      "ts-node/register",
      "source-map-support/register"
    ],
    "exit": true,
    "spec": "./tests/unit/**/*.ts"
  }
```

and running test coverage command

```
nyc mocha
```